# How to make every combinaison of element from a list of n lists with m elements? (Python)

Tags: list, python-2.7

From a list of n lists, each having different numbers of element, I want to get all possible combinaison.

I make an example to help understand my problem:

If I have a list of lists like this:

```
a = [['a','b'], ['c','d'],['e','f','g']]
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
[[('a', 'c', 'e')],
 [('a', 'c', 'f')],
 [('a', 'c', 'g')],
 [('a', 'd', 'e')],
 [('a', 'd', 'f')],
 [('a', 'd', 'g')],
 [('b', 'c', 'e')],
 [('b', 'c', 'f')],
 [('b', 'c', 'g')],
 [('b', 'd', 'e')],
 [('b', 'd', 'f')],
 [('b', 'd', 'g')]]
```

I get that with this:

```
list((zip(x,y,z) for x in a[0] for y in a [1] for z in a[2]))
```

Now I would like a function to do the same thing with any list of lists I pass too it. (No list is empty)

Something recursive like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186518/function-with-varying-number-of-for-loops-python) can maybe work, but I have a hard time figure it out and something less complex and faster is maybe possible.

I found a solution in java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169685/taking-one-element-from-each-list-in-every-possible-way), but I don't know java and I can't translate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an `itertools.product` function for this. Just unpack your list as arguments:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(*a))
[('a', 'c', 'e'), ('a', 'c', 'f'), ('a', 'c', 'g'), ('a', 'd', 'e'), ('a', 'd', 'f'), ('a', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'c', 'e'), ('b', 'c', 'f'), ('b', 'c', 'g'), ('b', 'd', 'e'), ('b', 'd', 'f'), ('b', 'd', 'g')]
```

Comment: OP wished for the tuples to be wrapped in a list, I think.

Comment: @JonathanEunice, I doubt it, I think using it in example was because that's what `zip` returned, not what he intended.

Comment: I agree it's quite unnecessary--the tuples should do just fine as first-level containers. I was just going by "I would like to get something like this:" followed by the boxed examples.

Comment: The tuples don't need to be wrapped, it an artefact of the way I found to do it. Thanks for your fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product

[[combo] for combo in product(*a)]
```

Yields:

```
[[('a', 'c', 'e')],
 [('a', 'c', 'f')],
 [('a', 'c', 'g')],
 [('a', 'd', 'e')],
 [('a', 'd', 'f')],
 [('a', 'd', 'g')],
 [('b', 'c', 'e')],
 [('b', 'c', 'f')],
 [('b', 'c', 'g')],
 [('b', 'd', 'e')],
 [('b', 'd', 'f')],
 [('b', 'd', 'g')]]
```

So for a function, you just need:

```
def boxed_product(somelists):
    return [[combo] for combo in product(*somelists)]
```